# Custom Label Provider not working in Backoffice for component="base"

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

**SAP Commerce 1811**

I have created one custom Label Provider for one of my custom item type and applied it for component="base" but its not working in Backoffice.

**CustomLabelProvider-** Created inside backoffice/src folder

```
public class CustomLabelProvider implements LabelProvider<CustomABCModel>
{  
    @Override
    public String getLabel(final CustomABCModel model)
    {
        // some custom logic
        return label;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(final CustomABCModel model)
    {
       return getLabel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public String getIconPath(final CustomABCModel model)
    {
       return null;
    }
}
```

**mybackoffice-backoffice-spring.xml**

```
<bean id="customLabelProvider" class="com.hybris.backoffice.labels.impl.CustomLabelProvider"/>
```

**mybackoffice-backoffice-config.xml**

```
<context type="CustomABC" component="base" merge-by="type">
    <y:base>
        <y:labels>
            <y:labels beanId="customLabelProvider"/>
        </y:labels>
    </y:base>
</context>
```

I have done all the steps but somehow its not working. Label not showing in Backoffice.

Any help on whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Labels` tag cannot have an under tag `labels`, this the related `xsd` structure for `Labels` tag :

```
<xs:complexType name="labels">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="label" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="shortLabel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="iconPath" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="beanId" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

So you probably wanted to do this instead :

```
<context type="CustomABC" component="base" merge-by="type">
    <y:base>
        <y:labels beanId="customLabelProvider"/>
    </y:base>
</context>
```

Answer (score 0):

label grouping is incorrect wrt XSD.

```
<context type="CustomABC" component="base" merge-by="type" parent="GenericItem">
        <y:base>
            <y:labels beanId="customLabelProvider"/>
        </y:base>
</context>
```